# Connected sum of two surfaces is a surface?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

IS the connected sum of two surfaces a surface? Im having hard time trying to see this. Can someone kindly help me? thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of connected sum?

Comment: the definition Is this: $#$

Comment: That definition isn't rendering for me (it shows up as a # in a black square).  Maybe edit it into your post?

Comment: My point was for *you* to explain what a connected sum is and answer your own question. I know what it is. What part of the issue do you not understand?

Comment: @Emprendedor: What you wrote is the notation, not a definition. If you sit down and carefully write the definition starting with the words "Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be 2-dimensional manifolds..." then you will see that the proof that the result is a manifold is essentially immediate.